# Managing a Big Matrix in R

Tags: r, memory, matrix, storage

R - I have a Square matrix of doubles 62589x62589 which when I save the matrix to an Rdata object, it is 28GB, is this an insane size or relatively normal, is there any way around this?

Comment: Keep in mind that's almost four *billion* doubles.

Comment: What do you need such a large matrix for?

Comment: @krlmlr It's Genomic Microarray data that I've done some analysis on and i've just ran a Pearson Correlation which made a square matrix of 62589 metapatterns, hence the large size

Comment: @user2253047: If you can afford zeroing cells that are close enough to zero, the sparse matrix approach should work for you. However, you should do this when creating the matrix.

Comment: Just to add to the other comments, I strongly suspect that your matrix is near-sparse.  If it isn't, then you've essentially got total noncorrelation (or total correlation), which is not a result worth saving anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a dense matrix there's not much you can do about it. The storage requirements for this matrix are roughly

> 6 * 6 * 10^4 * 10^4 * 8 bytes = 288 * 10^8 bytes = 28.8 Gigabytes.

8 bytes is the size for a `double`. You can use `single` values, this halves the size.

For [sparse matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix), the [`Matrix`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matrix/index.html) package by Douglas Bates and Martin Maechler is your friend.

Comment: R has no single type, though the ff package provides them as well as general out-of-memory support.

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure that you've looked into R packages designed specifically for microarray data. For example, Bioconductor has packages for microarrays (http://www.bioconductor.org/help/workflows/arrays/). There are certainly others out there though. If they are designed to work with similarly large data sets then these packages may have already addressed the problem.